# Why does progress drawable changes its size after setting it programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I have to set `progressDrawable` for `AppCompatSeekBar` programmatically but it leads to changing the `SeekBar`'s `progressDrawable` height after I set it for the second time and further. You can see what I mean below:

[image: Initially]
[image: After click]

What should I do to change this behavior? I already set `minHeight` and `maxHeight` to `12dp` as it was suggested in another answer.

`activity_main.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="12dp"
        android:minHeight="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:thumb="@drawable/my_thumb" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/change_seek_bar_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="Change seek bar" />

</FrameLayout>
```

`my_thumb.xml`:

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="23dp"
    android:height="23dp"
    android:viewportWidth="23"
    android:viewportHeight="23">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#B7BDC2"
        android:pathData="M11.5,20L11.5,20A9.5,9.5 0,0 1,2 10.5L2,10.5A9.5,9.5 0,0 1,11.5 1L11.5,1A9.5,9.5 0,0 1,21 10.5L21,10.5A9.5,9.5 0,0 1,11.5 20z" />
</vector>
```

`MainActivity`:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.change_seek_bar_button);
        SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);

        // sets it the right way
        setProgressDrawable(seekBar);

        // on button click it sets progressDrawable with wrong height
        button.setOnClickListener((view) -> setProgressDrawable(seekBar));
    }

    private void setProgressDrawable(SeekBar seekBar) {
        GradientDrawable progressDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
            new int[]{0xFF000000, generateRandomColor()}
        );

        seekBar.setProgressDrawable(progressDrawable);
    }

    private int generateRandomColor() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is in `ProgressBar.updateDrawableBounds(int w, int h)`. When it calls `mProgressDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, right, bottom)`, it doesn't really take into account that `progressDrawable` might not be equal to the height of the whole `View`. But initially this function is called when width and height are 0's and I guess that's why it works for the first time.

The problem is kind of clear, so the most obvious solution is to change bounds after setting new `progressDrawable`:

```java
button.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
    setProgressDrawable(seekBar);

    // converting 12 dp to pixels
    int desiredHeight = (int) (12 * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    Rect bounds = seekBar.getProgressDrawable().copyBounds();
    int actualTop = (int) Math.round((bounds.bottom - bounds.top) / 2.0 - desiredHeight / 2.0);
    seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds.left, actualTop, bounds.right, actualTop + desiredHeight);
});
```

And it actually solves the problem.